# different results using R or Libre Office calc

Tags: r, data-visualization, calc

I have this set of data

```
x       y  
0.5 306.3
1   622.3
2   1230.1
3   2017.7
4   2589
5   3175.4
6   3751.9
9   5585.7
12  7388.8
15  9218.8
20  12042.8
25  15056.5
30  18081.2
45  27095.3
60  35609.2
80  47263.1
```

When I plot x vs y with R I obtain an almost linear plot, when I plot them with Libre Office Calc I obtain a parabolic plot.

How is that possible?

Which one is the right one?

Comment: Excuse me, why did you delete the plot I went to the trouble of including for illustration? It was nothing other than a cleaner, larger (i.e. non-screenshot) version of the same plot you linked to in comments. Why remove it? If you included a link to the plot, you intended it to be seen. I made it easier to be seen, and in the correct context (in your question). What's up?

Comment: Sorry my mistakes, it's my first time with this forum and I still do not know how does it works.

Comment: Okay; I put it in my answer instead, so at least people can see it.

Answer (score 8):

From the look of your link below, you obtained this plot:

[image: OP's line plot]

It looks like you're just plotting y vs its *index* in Libre Office Calc.

Let's look at the difference - first in R:

R gives (using `plot(x,y)`):

[image: y vs x plot]

But if you plot y vs its index and plot lines (`plot(y, type="l", col=4)`), you get:

[image: y vs index as line plot]

If you don't tell Libre Office Calc to do a scatter plot, by default it does a barplot of the series. Instead you seem to have got it to do a line plot of just the $y$ series. You can, for example, get that (the top plot in my answer) by selecting the $y$ column and then **Insert**, **Chart** and then choosing **Line** and then clicking on the third plot, "Lines only".

Libre Office Calc will produce the correct plot if you tell it the right things:

[image: y vs x in Libre Office Calc]

You can do this as follows:

Select both data columns. **Insert** then **Chart**

The Chart Wizard window should pop up (if you're using a recent version, anyway, mine were done in 4.0.0.3).

Choose the **XY (Scatter)** option.

Click **Finish** (or choose one of the related plots there, like the line-and-points or the line-only plot and then click **Finish**).

Comment: My r plot is look like your. But my libre office plot is this one    https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3FIuCA5bZUaakNtNDhrWE5Vc1k/edit?usp=sharing On the x axes i do not have the index

Comment: thanks probability I'm making some mistakes with libre office is the first time I use it.  Thanks for help

Comment: Yes you do have the index of the $y$ points, it's just not *telling* you that you do.

Answer (score 0):

Just to reiterate what was mentioned above:

To have your provided values along the x-axis, you must choose "XY Scatter", and NOT Line graph or anything else...

So highlight your two columns of data, choose Insert -> graph -> XY Scatter, and it should create a "data range" for your "x axis". The "x axis" data range field does NOT appear and is not create-able (that I can tell) when you select a line graph...